# Как правильно написать регулярные выражения?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как правильно написать регулярные выражения для следующих моментов:

1. Как получить слово, идущее сразу за указанным словом `какое_то_слово нужное_слово`?
2. Как получить всё содержимое, которое расположено между скобками `(...)`?
3. Как получить всё содержимое, которое расположено между скобками `(...)`, игнорируя например `какое_то_слово(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `/какое_то_слово\s([а-яА-Я\_]*)/gm`
2. `/\((.*?)\)/gm`
3. `/\((?!игнорируемое_слово)(.*?)\)/gm`